# Event received for the system language change in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, system-settings

In Ubuntu, we can change the system language in user session or system wide. I have a usecase where I want to identify inside my running application if the system language has been changed. Is there some kind of event that the system sends across, whenever the system language is updated?

[image]